# how to fix 'java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private java.util.Objects() with no args'?

Tags: kotlin, gson

I'm trying to create an RSS reader using gson parse but I have a problem with the line `Gson().fromJson`. It's throwing the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private java.util.Objects() with no args

```
var rssObject= RootObject()

//here is the line where I've got the problem          
rssObject = Gson().fromJson<RootObject>(result, RootObject::class.java)
val adapter = FeedAdapter(rssObject,baseContext)
recyclerView.adapter=adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

This is were I take results:

```
override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): String {
    val result: String
    val http= HTTPDataHandler()
    result = http.GetHTTPDataHandler(params[0])
    return result
}
```

I'm using a dataclass with an empty constructor

```
data class RootObject(val status: String, val feed: Feed?, val items: List<Item>) {
    constructor() : this("", null, emptyList())
}
```